# Language requirements for IT-contractor working in Denmark?

Tags: information-technology

What languages are required (typically) for IT-Contractor who wants to work in Denmark?

Usually in bigger European countries (such as Germany, France) you are required to know its native language, but in case of smaller only English is required.

How it looks like in case of Denmark?

Comment: Your question is too localized. See this: http://freelancing.stackexchange.com/faq#close

Comment: What is too localized in my question? Do you think that only questions valid for the whole world are on-topic here? That would be too localized...

Answer (score 4):

While reading the title I thought you meant programming language and was about to edit the title.

I think even in Denmark, English is a must. That's also the case for "bigger European countries". As a matter of fact, in the IT-World it is the *de facto* language. Without you won't go far.

As a plus to English the native language (or at least enough of it to have a chit-chat with your coworker) is surely highly appreciated. So, even if you don't speak Danish now, learn some useful phrases and after a couple of months you'll be fluent enough.

Edit: I don't think that there is any general rule. Maybe ask them?

Comment: Well, but as a rule, you can't get a contract/job in Germany if you don't speak German (except special cases). So my question was specially if Danish is required.